# Should I turn off "Build Automatically" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Even I disabled the "Build Automatically", the realtime syntax checking still works, so seems the  "Build Automatically" is useless?

Should I just turn it off?

Comment: Unless it's causing an actual problem, why turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax checking isn't the same as building.

Answer (score 4):

Build automatically helps you know if there are any compile errors.
Its always a good practice to keep build automatically on as to ensure that you dont checkin any code that causes compile issues

Comment: That shouldn't be something left to an IDE, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton , i agree . But afterall we are humans, we tend to make mistakes some time :)

Comment: Thanks...but are there any example can only be detected by compiling but not run-time syntax checking?

Comment: IDE comes with those features. If you don't want to find error at runtime then you will have to use editor like Notepad (++0) and then compile it through command line using javac

Comment: I mean even when I disabled the auto compile, eclipse still check the syntax for me, seems no need to enable it.

Comment: @Howard I view that as a reason to leave it enabled. Why make yourself hit "build", or risk not building, or...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to wait for the compilation cycle whenever you want to run your program after small changes? "Automatic build" does this compilation in the background and therefore saves your precious time when launching the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven and you edit some classes during mvn build and autobuild is on, it can break build and leave it in unexpected state (doesn't have to end with error). But i still have it turned on, just not changing code while mvn building.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 'nice to have' feature because it gives you compile errors real-time.  People also hate it because they complain it distracts them while they are typing out a lot of code and half way through typing the screen is filled with a bunch of red lines.

But this nice feature comes at the cost of your CPU.  If I am on a slower machine or if I have other processes running that are CPU intensive then I turn off the auto-build feature.  At that point you have to manually hit the shortcut key to build your code.  Honestly you just get used to hitting the shortcut without even thinking after a while.